# Method pluralize seems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to generate a migration that creates a table called `creditcardquotas`, but rails generate a table called `credit_card_quota` exactly like the name of the model.

I tried with the method pluralize

helper.pluralize(2, 'quota')
   =>   "2 quota"

```
class CreateCreditCardQuota < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :credit_card_quota do |t|
          t.integer :credit_card_id
          t.integer :quotes
          t.integer :interest
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

How do I tell Rails migration that I want that the table called `credit_card_quotas`?

Comment: Why not use `create_table :credit_card_quotas do |t|` after the migration has been generated, before it is applied.

Comment: The model believe that table is called  CreditCardQuota CreditCardQuota.all      ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'credit_card_quota'

Comment: This is how it is in rails.. if you want it differently, add an inflection for pluralize. I'll post a pseudo-answer to guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in `config/initializers/`. Name that file `inflections.rb` and add this content in it.

Before adding you get:

```
helper.pluralize(2, 'quota') 
 => "2 quota"
```

Add the inflection:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
     inflect.plural 'quota', 'quotas'
end
```

After that:

```
helper.pluralize(2, 'quota') 
 => "2 quotas"
```

You can add any kind of valid or invalid pluralizations in this file...

Run the migrations after having applied this configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

In my recent experience, it seems like rails/active record does not know how to pluralize the word "quota", or that it thinks that the plural of the word "quota" is "quota". I just tried to create a new migration for a "quotas" table that was paired with a **Quota** class in **quota.rb**. In rails console, when trying to use this model, I saw this warning:

```
Quota(Table doesn't exist)
```

But when I updated my **Quota** class to be **Quotas** and renamed the file, I was able to use the quotas table in the db. My eventual solution was to change the db table name from **quotas** to **quota** and use the **Quota** class for my model.